# Real convexity of $f: I\to \mathbf{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Fix a continuous $f: I\to \mathbf{R}$, where $I$ is a non-empty real interval. Then, prove that $f$ is convex if and only if, for all $x,y \in I$, there exists $\lambda=\lambda(x,y) \in (0,1)$ such that
$$
f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) \le \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y).
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f$ satisfies the given condition. Given $x,y \in I$, define the set
$$S = \{ \lambda \in [0,1] : f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y) \}. $$
It is clear from continuity of $f$ that $S$ is closed, and $S$ is nonempty since $0,1 \in S$.

I claim that that for every $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in S$ (with $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2$) there exists some $\lambda' \in S$ with $\lambda_1 < \lambda' < \lambda_2$. Then if $[0,1] \setminus S$ is nonempty, we can let $(a,b)$ be an open interval which is a connected component of $[0,1]\setminus S$. But we must have $a,b \in S$ so, by the claim, $(a,b)$ must contain an element of $S$. From this contradiction we conclude that $S=[0,1]$, and $f$ is convex.

To prove the claim, take $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in S$ and let $x_i = \lambda_i x + (1-\lambda_i)y$ for $i=1,2$. By assumption, there exists some $\lambda \in (0,1)$ with
$$f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2) \leq \lambda f(x_1) + (1-\lambda) f(x_2).$$
Letting $\lambda' = \lambda \lambda_1 + (1-\lambda) \lambda_2$, we can rewrite the left-hand side as $f(\lambda' x + (1-\lambda')y)$. From the definitions of $x_1,x_2,\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, the right-hand side is at most
$$ \lambda[ \lambda_1 f(x) + (1-\lambda_1) f(y)] + (1-\lambda) [\lambda_2 f(x) + (1-\lambda_2) f(y)] $$
which can be written as $\lambda' f(x) + (1-\lambda') f(y)$. Therefore $\lambda' \in S$, and by definition of $\lambda'$ we see that $\lambda_1 < \lambda' < \lambda_2$. This proves the claim, and hence that $f$ is convex.

Comment: I like your proof (+1),  do you know any references about this kind of generalization of convex functions ..